# How close could two local maxima be?

Tags: calculus

How close could two local maxima be?

### Def

---

Let $f$ be a real function defined on a metric space $X$. We say that $f$ has a local maximum at a point $p \in  X$ if there exists $\delta  > 0$ such that $f (q) < f(p)$ for all $q \in  X$ with $d(p, q) < \delta$.

Local minima are defined likewise.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image]

#### Edit:

I'm also thinking two(or) more local maxima may degenerate to one? And In that case the distance between two maxima is arbitrary close maybe not so obvious?

Comment: The plural of "maximum" is "maxima".

Comment: @LeeSleek thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They can be as close as you want, since you can scale any graph $f(x)$ to become $f(nx)$, which shrinks it by a factor of $n$ in the x-direction.

---

If you consider the graph of $f(x) = \sin \frac{1}{x} , x > 0$, you can see that the local maxima can occur within any arbitrarily small distance that you want.

Comment: Hi, I've added another case, maybe something different.

Comment: @HyperGroups It can be as small as you want it to be. You need to clarify what you mean by otherwise, and perhaps start another question.

Comment: Ok, fine, Do you think it a valid question, when change the distance to the distance along the curve? i.e. arc length between two local maxima?

Comment: @HyperGroups Similarly, you can shrink it by a factor. Though the length doesn't exactly decrease by the same factor $n$, it does descrease. Alternatively, consider the constant function, where every point is a maxima.

Comment: @HyperGroups:  In the $\sin \frac 1x$ example, the arc length between two successive minima is not too different from $4$ for large $x$.  It is always greater, but by a small amount.